# how to add costume attribute to textfields or tabs in vaadin 6

Tags: javascript, html, vaadin

In our Medical Application we integrate Nunance's Dragon Speech Recognition. In API it called as SAS.

In One Dashboard We designed UI by using TabSheet of Vaadin framework. Tabsheet basicaly makes one tab (in html say div) visible and apply css property visibility:hidden to other tabs (divs).

SAS basicaly inspects all Input fields like textfield when onLoad() event occurs of Page. and it makes it speach enabled.

SAS clearly States " Hidden or disabled controls, i.e. controls with the disabled attribute or the CSS properties visibility:hidden or display:none, are excluded from speech recognition by default. This can be overridden by setting the 'data-nusa-enabled' attribute on these controls to "true" .​

Now My Question is how can I add this costume attribute to vaadin textfields or tabs component? We are using vaadin 6.8.

Comment: Can't you use javascript to set css properties?

Comment: No we cnt with 6.8 version

Answer (score 0):

As far as I experienced with Vaadin 6, a possible way to achieve something like this is to define a css rule in styles.css. In this rule you can define the visibility attribute, and then in your java code use the setStyleName()  method calling the rule to apply it to the component you need, but I don't know the behaviour of that rule on all the components, I just tested it in a Label and worked like charm.

Eg: In styles.css

```
.my-app .my-custom-tab {
    display: none;
}
```

In java code:

```
myTabSheet.getTab(tabIndex).setStyleName("my-custom-tab");
```

But beware, using the `display: none;` will hide your component, and if not visible (because another tab is actually selected) you will really not notice about it.

Remember to rollback it to its original state, setting a style with `display: inline-block;` or the one that fits your needs.

This is not the best solution because you must apply it to all the components you need to have that attribute, but is the "easiest" way I can think to achieve it.